# Why do we use correlation coefficient for feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I'm learning about feature selection.
I've found [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/) and seen many kernels checking the correlation coefficient matrix.
(In link above, they introduce 3 kinds of feature selection method and first of those is filter method including correlation coefficient and chi square test.)

Why can we use correlation coefficient for feature selection?

I think it can only indicate linear relationship between 2 variables so that it can't represent effect of combination of 2 or more variables or non-linear relationship.

So I wonder if correlation coefficient is appropriate for feature selection.
Why and how can it be used to feature selection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are completely right - correlation is naive, nearly primitive, method of feature selection. Consequently it will sometimes work (since data sometimes does follow the linear combination redundancy) and will fail miserably in many more complex tasks. There is no "golden" answer here. Correlation based feature selection is like logistic regression for classification - the easiest thing to try, but should not expect to solve any problem out there.

Comment: Thanks!  I have 2 more questions. 
1. Why do many people check correlation coefficient matrix? For checking redundancy of variables?  
2. Then could you recommend more effective or generally used method for feature selection?

Comment: 1. Yes, high correlation should suggest redundant variables. On the other hand lack of correlation does not really mean anything. 2. Feature selection at its very core is a hard problem as you want **discrete** decision, which prevents proper optimisation. Note, if you do it to make better classification - please don't. Feature selection should be only applied if feature gathering is expensive (for example in medical diagnosis). Typical non-linear feature selection mechanisms involve training models that can assign feature importance, such as Random Forest, and then dropping least important.

Comment: @lejlot Can you please expand on what you mean by "Note, if you do it to make better classification - please don't"? Is it not valid to apply feature selection to improve models by removing redundant features or poor predictors?

Comment: Next sentence of my comment is the explanation of what I meant - this is not what feature selection is designed to be doing. It can help to boost performance **if the model is weak**, but instead of using a weak model and a heuristic based feature selection - it is better to look for a stronger model (unless due to constraints on data one cannot train such a model, and has enough expert knowledge about particular problem to solve it through heuristics)